# Modify dictionary [String: [String]]

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

How can I insert and delete values ​​in a dictionary like this?

```
var example: [String: [String]]
```

In commit editingStyle I necessity remove value:

```
    if editingStyle == .delete {

       if indexPath.row >= 1 {

        let key = tableViewData[indexPath.section].dog
        let value = tableViewData[indexPath.section].name[indexPath.row - 1]

        let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
        tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)

        DataManager.shared.example.removeValue(forKey: key[value])

        }

  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: what does it mean by "like this?" Removing value is what you are doing already. You can do `example[key] = value` to insert.

Comment: Can you explain the structure of your tableView data source `tableViewData`. From the looks of it you are expecting this to be a model with custom properties set but I do not see that in your code or from your description

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to add and remove from the array that belongs to a given key in the dictionary

To add:

```
example[key]?.append(value)
```

Remove:

```
if let index = example[key]?.firstIndex(of: value) {
    example[key]?.remove(at: index)
}
```